# Determine the Taylor expansion of $f$ defined by $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x \ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I need to find the Taylor series, at $x=0$ for the piece-wise function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \displaystyle e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}} &\text{if}\, x \ne 0\\ 0 &\text{if}\, x = 0\end{cases}$$

I know that the Taylor series formula is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$. So I found the first 3 derivative of $f(x)$

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{2e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}}{x^2} &\text{if}\, x \ne 0\\ 0 &\text{if}\, x = 0\end{cases}$$

$$f''(x)=\begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{2(2e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}-3e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}x^2)}{x^6} &\text{if}\, x \ne 0\\ 0 &\text{if}\, x = 0\end{cases}$$

$$f'''(x)=\begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{2(12x^4e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}-18e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}+4e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}})}{x^9} &\text{if}\, x \ne 0\\ 0 &\text{if}\, x = 0\end{cases}$$

After that I bascially reformed the Taylor series equation as 
$$f(0)+\frac{f'(0)(x-0)^1}{1!}+\frac{f''(0)(x-0)^2}{2!}+\frac{f'''(0)(x-0)^3}{3!}+...$$
Since $f(0)=0=f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)$ is the Taylor series just $0+0+0+...$?

Comment: While your formulas for $f', f'', f'''$ seem to be correct, I suspect that part of your doubt comes from a lack of certainty about the value of $f'(0)$.  It's a common misconception, and one way to tell if you really understand the question is to ask yourself: how would you compute the Taylor series of the function below? $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{e^x-1-x}{x} &\text{if}\, x \ne 0\\ 0 &\text{if}\, x = 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Hint: if you think that this other function also has Taylor series $0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots$, then you are probably (improperly) missing the most important part of the original question :).

Comment: This is the classic example of a $\mathcal C^\infty$ function which is *not* the sum of it's Taylor's series.  In other words, *real* $\mathcal C^\infty$ functions are not necessarily analytic.

Comment: How did you prove that $f''(0)=0$? Not by considerig the limit of $f''(x)$ when $x\to0$, I hope...

Comment: @Did It's a piece wise function, where if $x=0, f(x)=f'(x)=f''(x)=f'''(x)=0$

Comment: Is this supposed to address my comment?

Comment: Yes, its is. @Did

Comment: It might be supposed to but it does not. Actually, it does a lot to convince your readers that indeed you "proved" that $f''(0)=0$ by considering the limit of $f''(x)$ when $x\to0$. Unfortunately, this does not show that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Taylor series is just $0$ as you had said.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by induction that for all $n\geq0$ one has 
$$f^{(n)}(x)=p_n\!\left({1\over x}\right)e^{-1/x^2}\qquad(x\ne0)\ ,$$
where $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $3n$. Furthermore we shall show that
$$f^{(n)}(0)=0=\lim_{x\to0}f^{(n)}(x)\qquad(n\geq0)\ ,\tag{1}$$
which completes the proof that $f\in C^\infty({\mathbb R})$.

The claim $(1)$ is true when $n=0$, by definition of $f$. Assume that it is true for an $n\geq0$. Then
$$f^{(n+1)}(0)=\lim_{x\to0}{f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(0)\over x}=\lim_{x\to0}{1\over x}p_n\left({1\over x}\right) e^{-1/x^2}=0\ ,$$
and $\lim_{x\to0}f^{(n+1)}(x)=0$ as well.

It follows that all Taylor polynomials of $f$ at $0$ are $\equiv0$.